# Path analysis with two mediators and reciprocal causation

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, path-model

I am trying to fit a path analysis which predicts a participant's binary choice of either a safe or a risky option. I am using a 2x2 design which includes multiple mediators. My big question is how to allow the mediators to change each other while still having a properly specified model. Or if that is not possible another way to properly analyze the model. The figure below gives the structure of the model.

[image]

Frame and Vividness are experimentally manipulated and each have two levels. Cognitive evaluation and emotions are continuous measures which come from what the participant wrote while contemplating the decision.

My understanding is that these sorts of nonrecursive path models require two-stage least squares or some other instrumental variable approach. However, I don't think I have a proper instrumental variable. So I've fit subsets of the full path model.

Using the `lavaan` package, I've fit two models: One with all paths seen in the figure but D, and one with all paths seen in the figure but C. The two models have basically identical fit indices and AIC/BICs, so, I'm not sure how to choose between the two models.

Is there a better way to estimate these effects than the two submodels? Am I missing something and am actually able to use an instrumental variable? Are there any good sources for this type of problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Yet, the second one should have one more degrees of freedom. Have you actually looked at the summary() and make sure they are indeed identical?

Comment: Thanks! You're correct. I had written models which had a path from vividness to cognitive evaluation. I just ran the correct models; the fit indices are basically identical and so is the AIC/BIC. I'll edit the question.